# What is best way to present a searchable/sortable list of data with entries having more than one title?

Tags: joomla

Building a web site with a data list (or directory) with some entries having more than one title. The entries need to appear in the list for each title. The list needs to function similarly to Linux's symbolic links where there are more than one directory entry pointing to the same data. Are there any recommendations on how to do this?

Comment: If you can show us some examples of how the titles and lists work, it might help to provide an answer.

Comment: Again, the best example/analogy is the Linux file system's (symbolic) links. In Linux, create a `file`. Create a `link` (or symbolic link) to that `file`. Both, the original file name and the new link name will appear when the `ls` command is executed. Try to read or edit the data located at `file` or `link` will give you the same data. Changes in one will appear in the other.

Comment: You might also like to ask this question at https://joomla.stackexchange.com where it might get more attention.

Answer (score 1):

Tags (in Articles) were invented for that.
Or Custom fields. Or a CCK. It is about a Many-to-Many relation, or One-to-Many.
Please specify your needs: what is the difference between your "entries" and your "titles"? What are they?

Answer (score 0):

One option may be to store the data in articles and create multiple menu options pointing to the same article.

A hidden menu (one that is not displayed explicitly on the website) can be created if there's no need to display the information in a menu.

You can configure the menu items to display the menu title as the page heading (rather than the article title) if you wish.

Menu items matching a search term will show up in Joomla search results.

Joomla does not offer any option to automatically sort menu items in a menu automatically but you can probably find a third party menu that can do this e.g. 
[Art Responsive Menu](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/art-responsive-menu) (free) looks like it has an option to sort by menu title.